# Android floating textview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

The title may not be accurate but here is what I want to achieve:

I have a layout header.xml which looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to control the display of a textview below the icon programatically. Below is how it looks when the textview is set to view.VISBILE:

[image]

I include this header in my Activity layout. I have a text view in my activity which has a top margin of 150dp. So, when I set the visibility of the icon's textview dynamically, the text in my activity is coming down. See below two images for comparision:

[image]

But even when the icon's textview is visible, I want the "Hello World" text to stay at 150dp distance w.r.t header when the icon's textview is set to view.GONE. So, I am looking for a kind of a floating view or something similar which will not take up space in the layout dimensions.

Note: This requirement is similar to a tooltip but I don't want to use any tooltip library.

Comment: maybe you can achieve this by using `app:layout_goneMarginTop=150dp` property, it will not change the hight even if you hide your view

Comment: I need to have the positioning to stay the same as left picture even when the icon's text view is present. Is that possible using app:layout_goneMarginTop=150dp? If yes, where should I include the property?

Comment: Maybe it works, please try this, you need to replace `marginTop` with `app:layout_goneMarginTop`

Comment: No luck. I was able to achieve the right picture using goneMarginTop. So even if the icon's text view is gone, the margin is 150dp and the "Hello World" is slightly lower. But I am not able to achieve the left picture.

Comment: please share your xml code

Comment: Try looking at [Android floating view(over other views)](https://askcodes.net/questions/android-floating-view--over-other-views-).

Comment: I found a solution using [popup window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow). Although this has satisfied my requirement, I had to hardcode the positioning to work on my device so I would say it is not ideal.